# I need to detect which language character or text entered in the box

Tags: windows-phone-7

There are many languages keyboard settings in windows phone. My objective is to make sure the user use the language I wanted. So, how can i detect the characters or text entered in the box is chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert the characters to bytes and check whether they fall into the chinese characters range in the unicode table. I don't know what are those ranges but should be something like here: http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0

Or you just can use a free language detection API for example Bing translator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512411.aspx